# Neo4j server activation error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory, java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: neo4j, port, filenotfoundexception, illegalstateexception

I tried to download neo4j today, and when I am trying to activate the server it does not work and giving me an error.
I am using neo4j-community-4.2.3 and JDK-11.0.10.

neo4j install-service completed and I typed eno4j start (no error occurred).
I tried to connect to the server with a web browser and it does not work.

I typed `neo4j console` and got this error

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-4.2.3\logs\debug.log (Access is denied)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:158)
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:678)
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:648)
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:205)
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.createRollingFileAppender(LogConfig.java:183)
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.getAppender(LogConfig.java:152)
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.configureLogging(LogConfig.java:105)
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig$Builder.build(LogConfig.java:290)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.createLogService(GlobalModule.java:337)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.<init>(GlobalModule.java:174)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.createGlobalModule(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:252)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:126)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36)
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134)
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35)
2021-02-26 21:16:37.044+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on dbms.connector.http.listen_address, a socket address. If missing port or hostname it is acquired from dbms.default_listen_address.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@375b5b7f] unable to create manager for [C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-4.2.3\logs\debug.log] with data [org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@1813f3e9[pattern=C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-4.2.3\logs\debug.log.%i, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=20971520), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=false), advertiseURI=null, layout=org.neo4j.logging.log4j.Neo4jLogLayout@28cb9120, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:115) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:205) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.shaded.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.createRollingFileAppender(LogConfig.java:183) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.getAppender(LogConfig.java:152) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig.configureLogging(LogConfig.java:105) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.logging.log4j.LogConfig$Builder.build(LogConfig.java:290) ~[neo4j-logging-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.createLogService(GlobalModule.java:337) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.module.GlobalModule.<init>(GlobalModule.java:174) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.createGlobalModule(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:252) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:126) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:36) ~[neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:134) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35) [neo4j-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
2021-02-26 21:16:37.075+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2021-02-26 21:16:37.075+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have administrator permissions.
If you encounter this problem run cmd as an administrator and then run the command.